# What is the best way to add two columns in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to do my homework assignment and I need some suggestion. I have a text file which contains numbers (two columns) which are separated by , . For example,

```
    123124 , 12312512
    5133421 , 12312412
```

There will be many more lines in the file. I need to add all numbers in the first column and second column (need to print out both). And then, I need to add both columns. So, my question is what is the best way to do the task? Thanks in advance. I was thinking about strtok() at first. But, it won't work as I need to print out the sum of the first column and second column.

Comment: Parsing the input data and writing your output here are separate concerns... Start by reading your input (for example using `scanf`) and writing what you parsed on standard output. Then the rest should be trivial.

Comment: Please don't use `scanf`, use `std::ifstream`. perhaps search on how to read data into a `std::vector`. (currently this question is somewhat to broad for Q&A)

Comment: @Galik: this job is accomplished in a way easier way with `scanf`, there's no reason to use `istream` inferior (at least for this kind of task) facilities.

Comment: @MatteoItalia `scanf` is not type-safe and `imo` not at all easier than using `C++` streams. Here are some reasons to prefer `C++` streams https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#iostream-vs-stdio

Comment: @MatteoItalia `myFile >> firstNumber >> comma >> secondNumber` is more appropriate (in C++ do as the C++ians). Easier and safer than C library functions.

Comment: @MichelBillaud: your example is both more complicated to read *and* wrong; try it with OP's input data. `comma` will contain whitespace, `secondNumber` will be uninitialized because it hit the comma; you'll happily read this garbage in because you didn't check the stream state. It should read `myFile >> firstNumber >> std::ws >> comma >> secondNumber;`. Then you have to check if `comma` is actually a comma and if the stream is still in `good()` state. Then tell me again with a straight face that it's "easier and safer" than `if(fscanf(fp, "%d , %d", &n1, &n2) == 2) ... `.

Comment: @MatteoItalia What do you do  lines with extra stuff ? In such exercises for beginners, input data is supposed to be valid, unless specified otherwise. Anyway it's safer to teach C++ I/O to C++ learners.

Comment: @MichelBillaud: your code fails exactly with the valid data provided by OP, go figure. Extra data at the end of lines is not handled explicitly - it's interpreted as if it was into the next line, exactly as the C++ solution. This can be easily fixed in both cases - but again, the point is that the `istream` solution makes even the "lazy" parsing case more complicated and error prone than necessary.

Comment: @matteo italia : I'm sure we all agree that both the operator>> and scanf versions require a lot of extra checking if we suppose, as you seem to do, that the input datafile may not be valid.  Were it the case, we would have a precise specification of what constitutes a valid treatment of input error cases.  BTW, no, it doesn't fail at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the values into two [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) objects:

```
// Example input data
std::istringstream in(R"~(

123124 , 12312512
5133421 , 12312412

)~");

// you can open a file instead and none of the
// other code changes:
//
// std::ifstream in("my_data_file.csv");

std::vector<int> col_1;
std::vector<int> col_2;

int i1;
int i2;
std::string comma; // used to skip past the commas

// we read in and test the results of the read
// as the while condition
while(in >> i1 >> comma >> i2)
{
    // We know the read succeeded here so we can safely
    // append the numbers to the ends of the vectors
    col_1.push_back(i1);
    col_2.push_back(i2);
}

// Did we get all the way to the end?
if(!in.eof())
    throw std::runtime_error("bad input"); // must be an input error

// process our vectors here

std::cout << "First column: " << '\n';

for(auto i: col_1)
    std::cout << i << '\n';

std::cout << "Second column: " << '\n';

for(auto i: col_2)
    std::cout << i << '\n';
```

Comment: Actually, my mistake, `comma` is an `std::string`. I'll do a dummy edit so I can remove the downvote and upvote instead.

Comment: Storing data in vectors is not necessary for this problem, as the third value can be computed line by line, and the totals can done on the fly.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Thanks for your help! I haven't try this code yet but will do later. I am thinking about strtok(). I will split the string and put everything onto 1D vector. Then I will do arithmetic operation on odd indices and even indices to get the sum of first column and second column. Do you think it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::ifstream is(argv[1]);

    for (;;)
    {
        int x1 = 0, x2 = 0;
        char sep = 0;

        is >> x1;
        is >> sep;
        is >> x2;

        // Validate the data.
        if ((sep != ',') or is.eof()) { break; }

        // Data tests valid, use it however.
        std::cout << "read: " << x1 << sep << x2 << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I really do not like scanf() and here is why. This will work:

```
int x, y;
fscanf("%d, %d",&x, &y);
```

If you change `x, y` to **short int** `fscanf()` will access invalid memory (boom).

If you change `x, y` to **long int** `fscanf()` will give you incorrect results.

Given these 2 choices I would strongly prefer the use of std::istream.

Comment: As I said in a comment above, this C++ solution is wrong. Read OP's data: you have to skip whitespace (`>> std::ws`) before reading in the comma. Also, you are just checking `.eof()`, which means that you'll get into an infinite loop on invalid data (as will happen on OP's example, as your `is>>x2` will hit the comma) or device failure; you have to check if the stream in `good()` state. Finally, the `scanf` point is moot; any compiler worth using will provide a warning if the format string and the arguments don't match. The real problem is again that you aren't handling errors correctly.

Comment: Also, don't use `endl` unless you *really* mean to flush the output buffer and slow down output redirected to file (which generally isn't needed).

Comment: @Matteo Italia, please show your code, with all error handling, so we can appreciate how easier and safer it is :-)